# Azure queue message should go to one receiver even if two receivers are listening to the queue, implementing in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm working with Azure Service bus queue, I have two listeners for the same queue, how can i make sure that one receiver1 should get the queue message all the time not the other one?

Note: 1. Implemented all the code in C#.
2. I'm aware about the Topics, above scenario is specific to queue.

Comment: Ideally you should be using `Topics and Subscriptions` for this kind of scenario. Is there a particular reason you are not using them?

Comment: What is the idea behind having 2 listeners but forcing just one to be actively consuming messages?

Comment: I was asked this in one of the interviews, I'm curious to know.